# Click event is not working after ajax call

Tags: javascript, ajax, events, click, dom-events

I have a parent jsp in which another jsp will be included. In the child jsp another jsp is included.

There will be a button in first child jsp, if we click that button ajax call will be triggered and this will append the div of second child jsp.

**Problem here is::** In the appended second child jsp, Javascript is not working.

```
function abc(){
    $("[id^=<%=KunalBean.getBeanFieldPrefix()%>rdxCarterz]").on("click", function() {
    alert("after ajax call")
});
}
```

I am calling this abc function on success call of ajax. After ajax call, the function `abc(`) is getting called, but the click event is not working. So when I click on the corresponding radio option, it does not work.

Please let me know what can be the solution for this problem.

Comment: have you check the object exists

alert($("[id^=<%=KunalBean.getBeanFieldPrefix()%>rdxCarterz]").length); and check number returned is not 0

Comment: Why not use delegation instead of adding a click handler after each call?

Comment: @Barmar Can you  let me know how to use event delegation her with an example ? I am not aware of it.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements

Comment: @Barmar delegation is used in older version of jquery.

Answer (score 0):

When trying to call event from a dynamically loaded object use this method

```
function abc(){
    $("body").on("click" , "[id^<%=KunalBean.getBeanFieldPrefix()%>rdxCarterz]",function({
     alert("after ajax call");
  });
}
```

Comment: I have  tried this way. It did not work.i cannot use $("body"),because i m including the same jsp at some other places in the application where ther e is no ajax call.it is affecting that palces also